# How to compose an image from GUI elements on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need to form an image by composing some visual elements and save it on disk. The question is: how to "screenshot" a certain area of a view? Possibly a view that is not visible, so the procedure can be executed unnoticed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet shows how to render a view to a `UIImage`:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And this snippet shows how to save a `UIImage` as a JPEG or a PNG:

```
NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() 
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() 
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```